# Collider overlap is not being detected

Tags: unity, collider

I am writing some logic to handle spawning objects into a game scene at a randomly generated location based on the size of a collider's bounds. The logic for getting the coordinates and instantiating an object in the corresponding location is working fine but I have logic I use to make sure that the object being placed is not colliding with any other colliders. To detect if the gameobject I have placed is colliding with anything I am using `Physics2D.OverlapCollider()`, passing in the collider of the gameobject. I get no colliders back though. Below is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
var x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xmin, xmax);
var y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(ymin, ymax);
var spawnedObjCollider = spawnedObj.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
spawnedObj.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0f);
Physics2D.SyncTransforms();

var overlappingColliders = new List<Collider2D>();
var numColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCollider(spawnedObjCollider, new ContactFilter2D().NoFilter(), overlappingColliders);
```

In the case that I'm looking at, the spawned gameobject is overlapping another collider but it acts like it doesn't see it. Both objects are on the default layer even though it shouldn't matter what layer they are on since I am passing in NoFilter(). (the small collider is the collider of the spawned object):

[image]

These are the collider settings, at runtime, for the spawned gameobject:

[image]

These are the collider settings, at runtime, for the collider that the spawned gameobject is being put on top of:

[image]

Comment: Do you get different results with `OverlapBox` / `OverlapArea`? or their `All`/`NonAlloc` versions?

Comment: So...I added back the Physics2D.SyncTransforms() and restarted unity and now it works. Welp

Comment: Maybe you accidentally synced the 3D physics transforms by leaving out the `2D` part in your first attempt? In any case, want to share that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must not have had Physics2D.SyncTransforms(); set correctly in my code after the position was changed. Adding that seemed to fix the issue.